# Can I use variable to fill xml with multiple values in ASP.Net c#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, xml

Hello everyone I am trying to create and save XML with values from SQL Server database.

My code basically creates an XML string filled with the variables that I get from several SQL queries (I need to fetch data from many tables to complete the XML)

I am using `SqlDataReader` to fetch values for my variables.

Since my XML will be kind of long and complicated, I decided to put the final XML strings from a few sub-strings according to the queries, basically like:

```
finalxml string = startxml + headerxml + buyerxml + sellerxml + linesxml + summaryxml
```

I was all OK till I reached a point, where a SQL query returned more than one row as a result.

Here is my code-behind:

```
string orderdetails = "select ProductId, Quantity from [Order] inner join OrderItem on [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId where OrderId='" + orderID + "'";
SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(orderdetails, dbConn);

dbConn.Open();

using (SqlDataReader orderitem = com3.ExecuteReader())
    while (orderitem.Read())
    {
            string orderxml = "<Order>" + "<OrderItem>" + orderitem.GetInt32(0).ToString() + "</OrderItem>" + "<OrderItem>" + orderitem.GetInt32(1).ToString() + "</OrderItem>" + "</Order>";
            Label20.Text = orderxml;
            string termid = orderitem.GetInt32(0).ToString();
            string termmenny = orderitem.GetInt32(1).ToString();
    }

    dbConn.Close();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string headerxml = "<Order-Header>" +
                            "<DocumentType> számla </DocumentType>" +
                            "<OrderNumber>" + rendSz + "</OrderNumber>" +   
                            "<OrderDate>"+ datum +"</OrderDate>" +   
                            "<ExpectedDeliverydate> " + szallido + "</ExpectedDeliverydate>"+
                            "<PaymentMethod>"+ fizmod +"</PaymentMethod>"+
                            "<Remarks><![CDATA[" + txtFirstName.Text + "]]></Remarks>"+
                            "<Note><![CDATA[" + txtLastName + "]]></Note>" +   
                            "<PreviousOrderNumber><![CDATA[]]></PreviousOrderNumber>" +
                        "</Order-Header>";
    string vevoxml = "<Buyer>" +
                                "<ILN>435</ILN>" +
                                    "<Name>"+ vezeteknev +" "+ keresztnev +"</Name>" +
                                    "<City>" + vevovaros + "</City>" +
                                    "<ZIP>" + irszam + "</ZIP>" +
                                    "<Address>" + vevocim1 + vevocim2 + "</Address>" +
                                    "<E-mail>" + vevoemail +  "</E-mail>" +
                                    "<Telefon>" + vevotel + "</Telefon>" +
                                    "<Contact>" + "nincs" + "</Contact>" +
                                    "<DeliveryName>" + szallkeresztnev +" "+ szallvezeteknev + "</DeliveryName>" +
                                    "<DeliveryCity>" + szallcimvaros + "</DeliveryCity>" +
                                    "<DeliveryZIP>" + szallcimirszam + "</DeliveryZIP>" +
                                    "<DeliveryAddress>" + szallvevocim1 + szallvevocim2 + "</DeliveryAddress>" +
                                "</Buyer>";

    string eladoxml = "<Seller>" +
                                    "<ILN />" +
                                    "<Name>E-Szoftver Kft.</Name>" +
                                    "<City>Budapest</City>" +
                                    "<ZIP>1195</ZIP>" +
                                    "<Address>Ady Endre út 97-99. F/04.</Address>" +
                                    "<E-mail>laszlo@marsalsoft.hu</E-mail>" +
                                "</Seller>";

    string linexml = "<Line>" +
                               "<Line-Item>" +
                                    "<LineNumber>1</LineNumber>" +
                                    "<EAN />" +
                                    "<SupplierItemCode />" +
                                    "<CustomsCode>5829</CustomsCode>" +
                                    "<ItemDescription><![CDATA[E-Számla szoftver frissítési és jogkövetési díj 1 évre]]></ItemDescription>" +
                                    "<ItemNote><![CDATA[]]></ItemNote>" +
                                    "<VATType>27</VATType>" +
                                    "<PackageType>CU</PackageType>" +
                                    "<OrderedQuantity>1</OrderedQuantity>" +
                                    "<UnitOfMeasure>év</UnitOfMeasure>" +
                            "<OrderedUnitNetPrice>13200</OrderedUnitNetPrice>" +
                                "</Line-Item>" +
                                "</Line>"; 


    string strMyXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"windows-1250\"?> " +
                      "<Document-Order>"+
                        headerxml +

                            "<Order-Parties>" +
                                vevoxml +
                                eladoxml +
                            "</Order-Parties>"+
                            "<Order-Lines>" +
                                linexml +
                            "</Order-Lines>" +
                            "<Order-Summary>" +
                                "<TotalLines>1</TotalLines>" +
                                "<TotalOrderedAmount>1</TotalOrderedAmount>" +
                                "<TotalNetPrice>13200</TotalNetPrice>" +
                                "<TotalVat>3564</TotalVat>" +
                                "<TotalGross>16764</TotalGross>" +
                            "</Order-Summary>" +
                     "</Document-Order>";

    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(strMyXml);

    xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("//orders//szamla.xml"));
}
```

Now the `lineXML` part is my problem, it describes the products, that is included in the order. Every xml describes 1 order, but 1 order can contain 3 products, and in that case I need to create a line for every product with a few elements: number, quantity, net price, gross price.

Is it possible with `SqlDataReader` and variable added to the string, or do I need to use some other way, like dataset generated from the query results?

I found a lot of info about generating xml from dataset, and generating xml with string, but none of them contained info about this particular situation, generating XML from SQL Server where you need to use multiple queries.

Luckily my code is modular, so if it can be done with dataset only, I don't need to touch the other parts of the xml hopefully. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered generating the XML server-side?  It is a lot easier for complex documents.  (Or, if you are going to do something client side, use `XElement` and such...)

Comment: The generation of xml should be processed by admin manually, after checking if every detail of the order is ok. If it can be done that way on server side, it can help if you can help me with that. I am not familiar with that,

Comment: Why not use the DataSet methods ReadXml() and WriteXml().

Comment: Like writing xml query by query and reading them and writing them in one piece in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution meanwhile, for the orderdetails part of my xml, I used a dataset, and instead of writing it to a file, I converted it into a string, and added it to the main xmlstring:

```
 string orderdetails = "select Rank() OVER (Order by ProductID) as LineNumber, null as EAN, null as CustomsCode, ProductId as SupplierItemCode, '![CDATA['+Product.Name+']' as ItemDescription, '![CDATA['+Product.ShortDescription+']' as ItemNote, null as VATType, 'CU' as PackageType, Quantity as OrderQuantity, 'darab' as UnitOfMeasure, UnitPriceExclTax as OrderedUnitNetPrice from [Order] inner join OrderItem on [Order].Id=OrderItem.OrderId Inner join Product on OrderItem.ProductId=Product.Id where OrderId='" + orderID + "'";
    SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(orderdetails, dbConn);

    dbConn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Line");

            try
            {

                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(orderdetails, dbConn);
                adapter.Fill(ds, "Line-Item");
                dbConn.Close();
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                string result = sw.ToString();

                ds.WriteXml(sw);
                ds.WriteXml(@"E:\mypath\Product.xml");  //saved to file as well just to check the correct scheme
                teststring = sw.ToString();
                prodlabel.Text = teststring;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label20.Text = ex.ToString();

            }
```